# No se sube la imagen en un formulario django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un formulario para subir ubicaciones, si quito el campo imagen del models.py se se me sube si no no! ¿ Sabrían donde podría tener el error?

Mi models. py:

```
class Ubicacion(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  lat  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  lng = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  imagen = models.ImageField()

  fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  TextoParaAudio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  Ruta = models.ForeignKey(Ruta,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Mi views:

```
 ddef upload_file(request):
print("ii")
if request.method == 'POST':
 form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES )
 print("FIle:"+ str(request.FILES))
 if form.is_valid():
    m = Ubicacion.objects.get(pk=id)
    m.model_pic = form.cleaned_data['imagen']
    m.save()
    return HttpResponse('image upload success')
else:
    print("no entro")
return HttpResponseForbidden('allowed only via POST')
```

Mi index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block title%}
Aplicacion en Django y Gmaps
{% endblock %}
{% block container%}

<div id="mapa" class="capas"></div>
<div id="datos" class="capas">

<div id="data">
    <select id="cars" name="cars" size="10">
        {% for ubicacion in ubicaciones %}
            <option value="{{ ubicacion.id }}"> {{ ubicacion.nombre }} {{ ubicacion.user }} - hace {{ ubicacion.fecha | timesince }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select><button type="button" id="deleteUbicacion">Eliminar</button>
</div>
<div id="form" >
    <form method="post" id="form_coords" id="upload_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" >{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="guardar" value="Guardar Ubicacion">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Actualiza lo que llevas de código según las correcciones, para comprobar que no funcione con el `enctype`. Por ahora lo que veo es que en método `upload_to` tienes un string vacío, intenta poner una función que devuelva un path, o por lo menos el filename, para que guarde algo, de lo contrario quizás ese sea el error, puedes agregar algo como esto: `upload_to=lambda x, filename: filename`

Comment: ya está actualizado! si pongo :  imagen = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file)(upload_file sin comillas)me da error de que no me importa ubicacionForm y el filename no me deja!
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hazlo con el lambda como te mostré en el ejemplo

Comment: lo he vuelto a actualizar y así no me sube!si lo pongo por separado no en ese formulario asi:class Document(models.Model):
 filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='')
si me sube!gracias

Comment: Tienrs puesto ddef upload_file(request):

Answer (score 0):

Te falta `enctype=multipart/form-data` en tu etiqueta `form`. Si sigue persistiendo el error comprueba tu `setting.py` si está bien la configuración de `media_url` y `media_root`. Por si acaso, también debes añadirle esto en `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: esto tengo en el settings:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
si hago un formulario a parte si se me sube!
y añadir eso a la url importo el debug_toolbar y me da error ImportError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'

Comment: ¿Has añadido el `enctype=multipart/form-data`?. No añadas lo de debug_toolbar, se me ha colado sin querer, perdona. imprime el `request.File` para comprobar que estas recibiendo los datos y también comprueba el form.is_valid si te está devolviendo un True. Puede que quien no te esté dejando guardar las fotos sea el formulario.

Comment: si, lo he añadido! parece que no me entra en el método upload_file, porque puede ser?

Comment: tienes dos id's en la etiqueta form, además dos id's distintas, si lo quieres es redirigir a esa función añadele un action.

Comment: He actualizado la peegunta, con el enctype y con el action, me sigue sin funcionar, que puedo estar haciendo mal?muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿has comprobado que la variable request.File esté rellena?¿has comprobado que form.is_valid() te devuelva True?

Comment: Acabo de comprobar que tu modelo tienes FileField. Si lo que quieres es guardar una imagen cambialo a ImageField

Comment: me da este error: AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'imageField' no consigo importar el imageField. Gracias

Comment: primera mayuscula. Instala la librería pillow ya que estás, la necesitas para usar ese campo

Comment: la variable file esta vacia: FIle:<MultiValueDict: {}> eso me devuelve! porque puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

He mirado tu código y estoy viendo esto:

```
if form.is_valid():
    newdoc = Ubicacion(imagen=request.FILES['imagen'])
    newdoc.save(form)
```

si tienes el objeto form cargado con los datos que le has pasado por el template ylo has validado, ¿porque cargas un objecto `Ubicacion` y le pasas dichos datos y luego llamas a la funcion `save()` y le pasas el formulario (otra vez).

Haz directamente `form.save()`.

Comment: parece que no me entra en el form.is_valid():

Comment: si no pasas el Form no puedo saber porque no está entrando en is_valid(). Actualiza la pregunta

Comment: esto:  form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None) ?

Comment: digo en la pregunta, pon el ModelForm como lo tienes ahora mismo

Comment: ya está actualizado, no me entra en el if , porque puede ser?   if request.method == 'POST':
Gracias

Comment: quitale el action y en enctype te faltan las comillas finales.

Comment: y como pondría el upload_file? lo he puesto con dos id pero no funciona!

Comment: si pones 2 id se pisan el uno al otro, los tag deben tener un único id. la forma de añadir un action es añadirle una url ya que el action sirve para mandar la información a una url distinta a la que estás en ese momento. Si lo que quieres es que te devuelva la información a la misma función que te da el formulario, no le pongas action directamente, de esa forma va a entrar a tu función

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal el formulario:

```
<div id="form" enctype=multipart/form-data>
<form method="post" id="form_coords" action="upload_file" >{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="guardar" value="Guardar Ubicacion">
    </p>
</form>
```

El atributo enctype va dentro de la etiqueta form.

Answer (score 0):

he encontrado un ejemplo de código que puede solucionar el problema que tienes con tu view, [subir imagenes django](https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield)